# References are not shown

Tags: bibliographies

I've written my LaTex file completely and used all my references, but no reference is displayed at the end of file. Wherever I've used a reference within the text, a question mark is displayed and nothing is displayed at the end.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using `bibtex` to compile your .tex file?  The compilation cycle is `pdflatex yourfile`, `bibtex yourfile`,`pdflatex yourfile`, `pdflatex yourfile` .

Comment: Could you show us a MWE please and explain how are you working on your references.

Comment: [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)

Comment: Thanks for you answers
Aradnix--- I don't know what a MWE is. Can you please tell me about it?
Harish--- if you mean the style of references, it's natbib.sty; but references are in a .bib file

Comment: A [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) is a  fully compilable document including `\documentclass{}` (`\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`) and the appropriate packages that *illustrates* the problem.

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\newcommand{\theHalgorithm}{\arabic{algorithm}}
\usepackage[accepted]{icml2013}
here:
\icmltitlerunning{CGA}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
\icmltitle{CGA}
\icmlauthor{Soorena}
\vskip 0.3in
]

\section{Introduction}
RIA and PMA are used RBDO approaches. Inner loop of these approaches consider different reliability analysis problems\cite{Aoues2010}.
\bibliography{REF}
\bibliographystyle{natbib}

\end{document}

Comment: and this is the cited article:
@Article{Aoues2010,
title = {Benchmark Study of Numerical Methods for Reliability-Based Design Optimization},
journal = {Structual and Multidisciplinary Optimization},
volume = {41},
number = {2},
pages = {227-294},
year = {2010},
author ={Y. Aoues and A. Chateauneuf}
}

Comment: hope that the above comments are helpful to make my question clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the line `\bibliographystyle{natbib}`, although you're using the `natbib` package, that isn't actually the name of any of the available bibliography styles. Try using `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` to get it working.

You'll find further information here http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php, which shows the different options for `\cite` and some of the available bibliography styles. If in doubt consult the full `natbib` docuumentation http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/

Comment: Excellent....... thank you very much. it's done

Comment: Good to know that you've got it working. If you're happy with the solution, please accept the answer by clicking on the tick to the left of the question.